# refreshing contents of blob in app engine using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob

is it  possible to fresh the contents of a particular blob every X seconds?like refreshing a image every second with the same blob key....can this be implemented??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Once blob is finalized it becomes immutable. See comments in [this example](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/FileService).

Comment: fine...then how to implement streaming?

Comment: You can append to the blob (even from multiple requests) until you finalize it. Once you finalize it, blob becomes read-only and available to be read.